# MinGW error Type '__m128i' could not be resolved in eclipse

Tags: mingw, eclipse-cdt, simd, sse2, sse3

In eclipse with MinGW I am trying to compile c code having some Intel Intrinsic Instruction (sse2 sse3). I have given compiler option  **-march=native -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1** but I am getting an error

> Type '__m128i' could not be resolved.

still I am able to build application but it crashing at runtime while executing the Intel Intrinsic Instruction. So I have go through header files of Intel Intrinsic Instruction it showing "SSE3 instruction set not enabled".

Please Help me to get out of this.

Comment: Which headers are you including ? `#include <xmmintrin.h>` ?

Comment: #include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
#include <pmmintrin.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>    these are files which I am including.

Comment: Can you show the whole gcc command line ?

Comment: gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -std=c99 -fmessage-length=0 -march=native -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1

Comment: And what CPU are you using ?

Comment: I tried on Two  different CPU -: 1- Core i7 4700 MQ Quad core 2.4Ghz      2- AMD A6-5200 APU Quad core 2.00GHz

Comment: OK - I can only guess that it's something funny with your mingw installation - from what you've told us this should all work fine.

Comment: Ok. I will try reinstallation of MinGw but I would like to know, Is it necessary that  xmmintrin.h file should contain SSE3 instruction set  enable code after installation or it will enable while compiling the application.

Comment: Just include the headers that you actually need - everything should just work. Consider also using Linux - doing gcc-based development on Windows is always a bit of a kludge.